# SSH "command not found" for Zsh

Tags: ssh, zsh

Im using Zsh on the client and server. When I use ssh to run a command on the remote server it can not find the binary:

```
ssh gt "cd /home/****/app/staging && bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=staging"
zsh:1: command not found: bundle
```

I can run the same command fine if I SSH in with an interactive shell.

On the server the `$PATH` is set in both .zshrc and .zshenv

**EDIT**

It appears `bundle` is not in my $PATH on the server. Maybe this has something to do with RVM (Ruby Version Manager) which hooks in to `cd`, so when you `cd` in to a directory with a `.rvmrc` file it sets up the Ruby environment and adds `bundle` to the $PATH. I need to find out if the `cd` hook is also triggered for non-interactive shells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path in which your binary is, is probably added to the `$PATH` variable **on login**. And when you run the presented command, it is executed via a *non-login* shell. The easiest (and safe) way of solving this is to specify a full path in this case.

Comment: As I read `man zsh`, the file sourced by non-login shells is `.zshenv`. This means that `bundle` is not found in the `$PATH` set in that file. Do a simple check `ssh gt 'echo $PATH'` (mind the **single** quotes!).

Comment: It looks like single quotes may have been the issue, changing from double quotes to single seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted the comment by @rozcietrewiacz, but I want to call it out as a full answer.  (This wouldn't have helped the poster who had already set both dotfiles, but I think it will help people like me who find this question based on the error.)

`zsh` reads `.zshenv` and `.zshrc` for interactive logins, but only `.zshenv` for noninteractive logins.  To fix this problem, I needed to split out the PATH settings from my `.zshrc` and move them to `.zshenv`.

In my case, I was unable to run mercurial commands that communicated by ssh with another server, because my path (with `hg` itself) was set in `.zshrc` on the server.

More detail can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout) and [here](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2012/msg00345.html).

Answer (score 0):

the reason is the PATH here.

please do a `which bundle` , on both the shells, that should be self-explanatory ! and you could either edit the PATH variable exporting it to your needs, or use absolute paths for the same.