# What should/shouldn't go in .zshenv, .zshrc, .zlogin, .zprofile, .zlogout?

Tags: zsh, startup

I'm looking for guidelines on what one should and should not include in the various startup files for `zsh`.

I understand the order of sourcing of these files, and the conditions under which they are sourced, but it is still not clear to me what should go in each.

Comment: see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html

Answer (score 544, accepted):

Here is a non-exhaustive list, in execution-order, of what each file tends to contain:

1. `.zshenv` is *always* sourced. It often contains exported variables that should be available to other programs. For example, `$PATH`, `$EDITOR`, and `$PAGER` are often set in `.zshenv`. Also, you can set `$ZDOTDIR` in `.zshenv` to specify an alternative location for the rest of your zsh configuration.
2. `.zprofile` is for login shells. It is basically the same as `.zlogin` except that it's sourced before `.zshrc` whereas `.zlogin` is sourced after `.zshrc`. According to the zsh documentation, *"`.zprofile` is meant as an alternative to `.zlogin` for ksh fans; the two are not intended to be used together, although this could certainly be done if desired."*
3. `.zshrc` is for interactive shells. You set options for the interactive shell there with the `setopt` and `unsetopt` commands. You can also load shell modules, set your history options, change your prompt, set up zle and completion, et cetera. You also set any variables that are only used in the interactive shell (e.g. `$LS_COLORS`).
4. `.zlogin` is for login shells. It is sourced on the start of a login shell but after `.zshrc`, if the shell is also interactive. This file is often used to start X using `startx`. Some systems start X on boot, so this file is not always very useful.
5. `.zlogout` is sometimes used to clear and reset the terminal. It is called when exiting, not when opening.

You should go through [the configuration files of random Github users](https://github.com/search?q=zsh+dotfiles&ref=commandbar) to get a better idea of what each file should contain.

Comment: Be aware when setting ``$PATH`` in ``.zshenv``, various other files all are sourced after this file that will override this value. See http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2003/msg00600.html.

Comment: Just for my own notes / confirmation and to help anybody else, the ultimate order is `.zshenv` → [`.zprofile` if login] → [`.zshrc` if interactive] → [`.zlogin` if login] → [`.zlogout` sometimes].

Comment: re: setting `$PATH` in `.zshenv` - macOS, as of Big Sur and at least a few versions prior - overwrites any changes to `$PATH` when `/etc/zprofile` is executed (after `.zshenv`).

Comment: @BeauBarker should $PATH be located in `.zshrc`?

Comment: @alper GitHub user `thoughtbot`'s popular dotfiles do indeed [recommend setting the $PATH in `.zshrc`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/dotfiles/blob/65cc8ef0848805395a8d21c9cb7d077874dd430d/zshenv#L20-L22).

Comment: @LyndsySimon This is not the case with Monterey. `/etc/zprofile` runs a utility called `/usr/libexec/path_helper` which appends values to the existing `PATH`.

Comment: Be aware that in between `.zshenv` and `.zshrc` the `/etc/zshrc` is sourced and things like `HISTFILE`, `HISTSIZE` are unconditionally overwritten / set there so those variable should be set in `.zshrc` or `.zlogin`

Answer (score 182):

Here a list of what each file should/shouldn't contain, in my opinion:

### .zshenv

*[Read every time]*

This file is always sourced, so it should set environment variables which need to be **updated frequently**. *PATH* (or its associated counterpart *path*) is a good example because you probably don't want to restart your whole session to make it update. By setting it in that file, reopening a terminal emulator will start a new Zsh instance with the *PATH* value updated.

But be aware that this file is **read even when Zsh is launched to run a single command** (with the *-c* option), even by another tool like `make`. You should **be very careful to not modify the default behavior of standard commands** because it may break some tools (by setting aliases for example).

### .zprofile

*[Read at login]*

I personally treat that file like `.zshenv` but for commands and variables which should be set once or which **don't need to be updated frequently**:

- environment variables to configure tools (flags for compilation, data folder location, etc.)
- configuration which execute commands (like `SCONSFLAGS="--jobs=$(( $(nproc) - 1 ))"`) as it may take some time to execute.

If you modify this file, you can apply the configuration updates by running a login shell:

```
exec zsh --login
```

### .zshrc

*[Read when interactive]*

I put here everything needed only for **interactive usage**:

- prompt,
- command completion,
- command correction,
- command suggestion,
- command highlighting,
- output coloring,
- aliases,
- key bindings,
- commands history management,
- other miscellaneous interactive tools (auto_cd, manydots-magic)...

### .zlogin

*[Read at login]*

This file is like `.zprofile`, but is read after `.zshrc`. You can consider the shell to be fully set up at .zlogin execution time

So, I use it to launch external commands which do not modify shell behaviors (e.g. a login manager).

### .zlogout

*[Read at logout][Within login shell]*

Here, you can clear your terminal or any other resource which was setup at login.

## How I choose where to put a setting

- if it is needed by a **command run non-interactively**: `.zshenv`
- if it should be **updated on each new shell**: `.zshenv`
- if it runs a command which **may take some time to complete**: `.zprofile`
- if it is related to **interactive usage**: `.zshrc`
- if it is a **command to be run when the shell is fully setup**: `.zlogin`
- if it **releases a resource** acquired at login: `.zlogout`

Comment: `.zshenv` is read before `/etc/zprofile` and that script will probably overwrite your `PATH` setting. I wouldn't use it at all. `.zshrc` runs for all interactive shells so it will run if you even just type `zsh` on the command line. That's where I'd put frequently changed things.

Comment: @JeremyP My `/etc/zsh/zprofile` does not set my PATH. And, I would think it would problematic for `/etc/zsh/zprofile` to assume that it can clobber `PATH`. Is there actually a distro that does this?

Comment: where would you put `startx` then?

Comment: @fedemengo You probably want to start your X server when everything is setup when loging in. The `.zlogin` file is perfect for that usage.

Answer (score 4):

For people who came here hoping to find a simple solution that is easy to remember and to maintain, here's the setup I use and recommend (at least for Mac OS users):

[image]

1. Put everything common in `.zshenv` and `.bash_env`, the other ones should now be empty and can be deleted (unless shell-specific, see step 4)
2. Make sure you have the same content in `.zshenv` and `.bash_env`
3. Remove content of `.bash_env` and put this inside instead so you have everything in a single place

```bash
   if [ -f $HOME/.zshenv ]; then
           source $HOME/.zshenv
   fi
```

4. Create `.zlogin` and `.bash_login` so that you can override the content of `.zshenv/.bash_env` on a per-shell basis (since they execute after).
5. (optional) Monitor `.zprofile`, `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.zshrc` from time to time, because some installers may create and append content in them automatically.

Comment: Why not use .zshrc ?  I put lots of things in it.

Comment: @GoodPen You can, I just love simplicity so I prefer to use `.zlogin` instead, that executes at the very end of the flow.

Comment: `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` are typically used to configure the look and feel of the interactive shell. For example, customizing the prompt, font color, etc. could be done here. See this answer for more insights https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324391/297265