# .zshenv not sourced on ssh login?

Tags: ssh, zsh, environment-variables, login, path

According to [the docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html)

> `.zshenv` is sourced on all invocations of the shell, unless the -f option is set. It should contain commands to set the command search path, plus other important environment variables. `.zshenv` should not contain commands that produce output or assume the shell is attached to a tty.

Okay, cool, so I would assume that logging in via ssh is considered an invocation of zsh... but maybe not?

```
wayne@arglefraster ~ 
⚘ echo $PATH                                                                                                   10:01:17
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
wayne@arglefraster ~ 
⚘ zsh                                                                                                          10:01:20
e%                                                                                                                      
wayne@arglefraster ~ 
⚘ echo $PATH                                                                                                   10:01:24
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/wayne/.rvm/bin:/home/wayne/.bin:/home/wayne/.local/bin
```

Those extra bits of path are added in my `.zshenv` file.

Is this normal, or do I have something wonky going on? Should I move my PATH modifications elsewhere?

Comment: You have `zsh` as your default shell in `/etc/passd` or you start it somehow different?

Comment: @Jakuje almost added this to the question: `wayne:x:1000:100::/home/wayne:/bin/zsh`

Comment: Use `zsh -o SOURCE_TRACE` to confirm what files are being read, and then `zsh -x` to see what configuration is done, in particular for `PATH`, in the event something else is trampling the `.zshenv` changes.

Comment: See this answer, which is probably what you want. mark it as chosen if it is. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/752811/3285

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`zshenv` is indeed read by every instance of the shell, but it is read *first*, before anything else. Your `$PATH` is probably getting reset in `zprofile` (`~/.zprofile` or `/etc/zprofile`, ...).

`zshenv` is not a good place to set your `$PATH`. It belongs in `zprofile`, which has the job of setting up the environment upon login. Setting environment variables in `zshenv` means among other things that they will get clobbered when running simple `zsh` subshells or `zsh` scripts within one session.

Comment: Well, it definitely wasn't getting reset in `~/.zprofile` *or* `/etc/zprofile`, as I have neither of those files. Nor `~/.zshrc`, as there's no `PATH` variable there. But, setting the PATH in `~/.zprofile` does appear to work properly. Following @thrig's comment, it *may* have been the virtualenvwrapper, though it seems strange that it would totally clobber the `PATH`

Comment: I'm confused. This is the opposite of this answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout) which says `~/.zhsenv` should have the `$PATH` .

Answer (score 0):

## Confirm you're in Z shell and that's your login shell

`.zshenv` is supposed to run when you ssh into a machine. If it doesn't run,

- Check that you're in Z shell when you ssh into a machine with `echo $SHELL`
- If you're not in Z shell, run `zsh` which will explicitly start Z shell and confirm your `.zshenv` works. If it does, run `exit` to drop back out of Z shell.
- If the file works, change your login
  shell,

  - While logged in via ssh
  - Run `command -v zsh` so you know where Z shell is, if this returns nothing you need to install Z shell
  - then run `chsh` and provide it the path to Z shell
  - Log out and log back in with ssh.