# $PATH by itself vs echo $PATH

Tags: bash

When I type just `$PATH` as below, the output starts with  `-bash:` followed by the value of `$PATH` then at the end it prints `: No such directory`
whereas the output of `echo $PATH` does not produce that output.
Is the bash's `readline` involved?

```
[user1@Server1 ~]$ $PATH
-bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user1/.local/bin:/home/user1/bin: No such file or directory
```

When I just do `echo $PATH` the output is:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user1/.local/bin:/home/user1/bin
```

Comment: `$PATH` tries to run your PATH as a command, `echo $PATH` outputs your PATH.

Comment: I'm curious, what did you want `$PATH` to do?

Comment: Look at the end of the output, not only the beginning: `No such file or directory`. Bash is not finding the `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin[...]` executable, and hence the error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first word on a simple command line is a command - an action. (There are more complex variants but for now consider this as a sufficient truth.)

In your first example, the "command" is the value of the `$PATH` variable, which isn't actually a command, so `bash` complains that it can't find it to run. (The shell searches the colon-separated list of directories specified in the `$PATH` variable for the command that you've entered.)

In your second example, the "command" is the `echo` verb, with the value of `$PATH` as its argument. The `echo` command prints its arguments to *stdout*, so you get to see the value of `$PATH` on the screen.

Comment: understood! I treid below commd [user1@Server1 ~]$ abc:def and the output is below. This makes sense. I still don;t understand teh first word of the output - "-bash" 
-bash: abc:def: command not found

Comment: @RaviKumar The `-bash` identifies the process that is reporting the error. The `-` in front of `bash` is a common way for a shell to say "I'm a login shell".

Answer (score 13):

If you type the command

```
$ cat food
```

you’ll get the error message

```
cat: food: No such file or directory
```

---

If you type the command

```
$ cp abc def
```

you’ll get the error message

```
cp: cannot stat ‘abc’: No such file or directory
```

---

It’s very ***very*** common for error messages in Unix & Linux
to begin with the name of the program that issued (i.e., wrote) them. 
So, when you type

```
$ abc:def
```

into a bash shell, it’s only natural that the error message

```
-bash: abc:def: command not found
```

begins with the name `bash`, because bash issued that message. 
The one part that’s a little tricky
is that it says `-bash` instead of `bash`. 
This occurs because bash is a ***shell***,
and specifically, a ***login shell***. 
By convention, the names of login shells always begin with a **`-`**.

For more background information on this, see:

- [What is the exact difference between
  a ‘terminal’, a ‘shell’, a ‘tty’ and a ‘console’?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/80216)
- [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175/80216)
- [WHY a **login** shell over a **non-login** shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/324359/80216)
- [What is the difference between interactive shells,
  login shells, non-login shell and their use cases?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50665/80216)
- [`.profile` and `.bash_profile` ignored
  when starting tmux from `.bashrc`?](https://superuser.com/q/614277/354511)
- [What does `exec $SHELL -l` do?](https://superuser.com/q/526890/354511)

Answer (score 4):

`$PATH` just evaluates the variable and tries to run that as a command, since there are no arguments nor actual command name, then it complains as: `no such file or directory`.

`echo $PATH` is explicitly giving a command to display the contents of the `$PATH` variable.

Answer (score -2):

This is equivalent to

```
export myvar="echo test"
$myvar
```

bash expands myvar and executes the result of variable.

The output in this case is

> test

Comment: When you type in `$: export myvar="echo test"` followed by return you'll get `-bash: $:: command not found`

Comment: @Anthon The $: may be his prompt. It is not a command then.

Comment: @peterh Yes I know, and although I realised, but since that is not standard (`$` I would expect but `$:`) that should be more clearly indicated (and formatted). It could also be that those two (or three) lines are the name of an executable program (name embedded with newlines), and executable that prints `test` to stdout.