# Confused between "echo command | ssh server" and "ssh server command"

Tags: scripting, login

During the course of my learning about the non-interactive login shell, I have come across 2 ways to remotely execute the commands via SSH. For me, they both look to be the same. But unfortunately, they aren't.

With the command `echo "shopt login_shell; echo \$-" | ssh -l poweruser 192.168.1.67`, I get the following output.

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
poweruser@192.168.1.67's password:
login_shell     on 
hBs
```

But with the command `ssh -l poweruser 192.168.1.67 "shopt login_shell; echo \$-"`, I get a different output.

```
poweruser@192.168.1.67's password:
login_shell     off
hBc
```

Could you please tell why the shell is not a login shell in the second case even though it prompts for the password.

Comment: As a side note, `ssh -t server cmd` is a better equivalent to `echo cmd|ssh server` as without -t, the default for no explicit command (`ssh server`) is to open a pseudo-terminal whereas the default for with a command (`ssh server cmd`) is NOT to open one. The -t forces it to open one anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`man ssh` documents that](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#DESCRIPTION):

> If a *command* is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.

The reason is then that in one case you specified a command, and in the other you didn't, and `ssh` deliberately (by design) behaves differently in those cases.

In the one where you didn't provide a command, a login shell was launched and it read the piped input and executed it. In the one where you did provide a command, it was launched instead.

Prompting for the password is unrelated. That is authenticating you to the server, before the shell or command is launched.

Answer (score 0):

This is imprecise, but it may be a useful way to look at it:

- `echo … | ssh …` “looks like” an interactive session —
  `ssh` is reading shell commands from its standard input after it starts. 
  Now, of course, `ssh` *can* distinguish
  between its stdin being a pipe or a tty (or a file),
  but it might not bother to do so. 
  Treating a pipe differently from a tty
  might make it harder to use something like [`expect`](https://www.nist.gov/publications/using-expect-automate-system-administration-tasks) ([man page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html)).

  `echo … | ssh …` feels like calling somebody on the phone
  and asking them to do something. 
  Potentially, you want them to do it *immediately*
  (while you’re still on the phone),
  and so a login shell feels more appropriate.
- With `ssh … command`,
  you’re specifying the command(s) to run
  before `ssh` even makes the connection. 
  You can’t possibly do something conditionally, based on responses you see
  (except maybe hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> if something goes wrong). 
  So it can’t be interactive; it’s more like [batch processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing).

  It feels like sending somebody an email and asking them to do something. 
  You don’t expect an immediate response,
  and so a login shell feels less appropriate.

For background, see [Why a "login" shell over a "non-login" shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/324359/80216)
(where — disclosure — the only answer was written by me)
and [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175/80216) — although,
after a very quick glance,
I don’t see anything there that’s directly relevant to this question.