# What is the Bash equivalent to .zshenv?

Tags: bash, zsh, environment-variables

I've read that `.bashrc` [(like `.zshrc`)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71253/3358) is meant only for interactive logins (and the one non-interactive exception of remote shells).  But where should environment variables for Bash be placed that is (roughly) equivalent to `.zshenv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the `$BASH_ENV` environment variable.

`info bash BASH_ENV`:

> `BASH_ENV`
> If this variable is set when Bash is invoked to execute a shell
> script, its value is expanded and used as the name of a startup
> file to read before executing the script.  *Note Bash Startup
> Files::.

So you'd set that variable to `~/.bashenv` for instance in your `~/.profile` for all non-interactive bash instances though not the ones invoked as `sh` to interpret code in that file upon startup.

To do that for interactive ones as well, you can add a `source ~/.bashenv` to your `~/.bashrc` (maybe also in your `~/.bash_profile` if it doesn't already source your `~/.bashrc` when interactive).

Comment: If you set `$BASH_ENV` in your `~/.profile`, then isn't `~/.profile` the one closest to `/.zshenv` for Bash?

Comment: `~/.profile` is like `~/.zprofile`, it's the login session initialisation file. You can set env vars that will be inherited by commands started within that session there.