zsh, macOS: Which file should be used to modify the $PATH variable, and how exactly?
What is the correct way to add something to the $PATH variable on macOS?

For example, I can do it in .zshrc:
path+=$HOME/foo/bar


...but it seems in such a case the modified path will be available for the interactive use only, and therefore the more robust solution is to put it in .zshenv instead.

...But on the other hand some people say (see comments to this answer) that modifying the path in .zshenv is not a good idea. (And, if I understand correctly, they assume the path should be changed in .zshrc or maybe using some another way...)

I also read this and this articles.


Nevertheless, I still don't understand which file to use for this, and how exactly. Could anybody explain it like I'm five?

ZSH supports different startup files that are run either for every shell, for interactive shells or for login shells: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide02.html Most likely restricting the PATH change to login shells does not make sense, so the question is: Do you need the directory in PATH only for interactive shells or for every shell, i.e. also for shell scripts. The answer might depend on what programs are in this directory and in which situation you need them.

@Bodo "Do you need the directory in PATH only for interactive shells or for every shell, i.e. also for shell scripts." - I would prefer it for every shell.

@Bodo "The answer might depend on what programs are in this directory and in which situation you need them." - I want to use this directory, that is $HOME/foo/bar, as a single place to store any of my scripts and configuration files. Thas it to say, the files and use cases may vary greatly.

Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification.

TLDR:
I suggest to use ~/.zshenv and to check the other files that your change does not get overwritten.

Citing https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide02.html, 
section 2.2: All the startup files:


/etc/zshenv Always run for every zsh.

~/.zshenv Usually run for every zsh (see below).

/etc/zprofile Run for login shells.

~/.zprofile Run for login shells.

/etc/zshrc Run for interactive shells.

~/.zshrc Run for interactive shells.

/etc/zlogin Run for login shells.

~/.zlogin Run for login shells.



This leads to the conclusion that you should use ~/.zshenv to add you user specific directory to PATH for all Zsh instances.
Regarding the comments to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71258 : I understand the concern that other files get sourced after ~/.zshenv, and these might overwrite your changes to PATH instead of adding to PATH. I suggest to check the other startup files named above if this is the case .
